# React Native / Expo: how to disable press actions while swiping, like all apps in fact do

Tags: react-native, scroll, expo, gesture

I have been working on an app for a while now, and I just can't figure out how to fix the following issue.

I have an horizontal scroll view:

```
<ScrollView
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        my={5}
      >
        {parcour_list?.map(parcour =>
          parcour.parcour ? (
            <ParcourTile navigation={navigation} key={parcour.id} parcour={parcour} />
          ) : null
        )}
</ScrollView>
```

And my 'ParcourTile' component is the following:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('parcour', { parcour })}>
      {({ isPressed }) => (
        <View
          mr={5}
          style={{
            width: 150,
            backgroundColor: isPressed ? 'rgba(255,255,255,0.05)' : null,
            transform: [
              {
                scale: isPressed ? 0.96 : 1
              }
            ]
          }}
        >
          <Image
            cacheKey={parcour.name}
            style={{ width: 150, height: 150, borderRadius: 8 }}
            source={parcour.image}
            alt={parcour.name}
          />
          <Heading color="white" size="xs" mt={2.5}>
            Hindernis {parcour.number}
          </Heading>
          <Heading color="white" size="md" mt={0.5}>
            {parcour.name.length > 20 ? `${parcour.name.slice(0, 23)}...` : parcour.name}
          </Heading>
        </View>
      )}
</Pressable>
```

Now, my problem is this: when I press, I want to select the tile and thus trigger the navigation action. Even when I just press rapidly. But, when I scroll, I dont want the 'isPressed' triggered.

At this moment, when I put my finger on the screen to start scrolling, the 'isPressed' is triggered. When I then start to scroll, 'isPressed' is no longer triggered.

But when I use whatever app (for example Facebook, Instagram or WhatsApp), this does not happen. When I start scrolling, the item on which my finger touches the screen first is not selected, only if I hold my finger on the item without scrolling for half a second or so, then it gets selected.

It's however not a press delay, because when I very rapidly tap the item (a chat in WhatsApp for example), the chat gets selected and opens.

I am trying for a long time to find something for this problem, but I just can't figure it out. I seems like such a small thing. Hope someone can help me here.

Amongst other possible solutions, I tried already an unstable_pressDelay, but while this fixes the scrolling problem, it also puts a delay on the normal press, which is not what I am looking for.